# .htaccess code and wildcard redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, wildcard-subdomain

Sorry if this topic is not unique, but believe me, I've searched alot.

I've a website that users can subscribe and have a unique web page for themselves with address like this:

http://website.com/api/username

Now, I want to make them able to access their pages using addresses like this:

http://username.website.com

In fact, username comes here as a subdomain.

and I know I have to add a wildcard a record (* as name and website IP as address). I've made this changes.

But I couldn't find any .htaccess code working for my problem.

could you help me please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming you have configured your DNS correctly, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407029/htaccess-subdomain-rewrite) seems to contain your answer.

Comment: redirect happen with this code:
RewriteEngine On
 # Extract the subdomain part of domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.2nate\.com$ [NC]
 # Check that the subdomain part is not www and ftp and mail
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
 # Redirect all requests to the original url  /blog
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://2nate.com/beta1/api/%1 [L]